# Strapi GraphQL API - 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: api, heroku, graphql, cors, strapi

I've just deployed my Strapi API to production following the docs: https://strapi.io/documentation/v3.x/deployment/heroku.html

And by making POST requests from other origins, I get this error:

[image]

Since my API works finally on development (localhost to localhost) I presume that the issue is related to CORS, and if it's, that's the cors configuration that I've set on the API:

`config/env/production/security.json`:

```
{
  "cors": {
    "enabled": true,
    "origin": "*"
  }
}
```

`config/env/production/middleware.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  settings: {
    cors: {
      enabled: true,
      origin: "*",
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: What are the exact error messages that the browser is logging in the devtools console?

Comment: On a side note: Something everyone should explore first is simply running `npm run dev` on your project(s). This cleared up my 405 error with Strapi after modifying a model and route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was added the cors config on the development environment...

In order to change the cors config on the production environment, the above code should be placed on the following path:

```
config/env/production/security.json 
config/env/production/middleware.js
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was missing route in `api/blog/config/routes.json`

```
{
  "method": "POST",
  "path": "/blog",
  "handler": "blog.create",
  "config": {
    "policies": []
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, since I use GraphQL for queries I should add `/graphql` at the end of the production URL as we do for `localhost:1337/graphql`.